# How to "transform" an array in a sentence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, sentence

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and I would like to "transform" an array of strings in a sentence including punctuation. That is, if I have an array like the following:

```
["element 1", "element 2", "element 3"]
```

I would like to get\build:

```
# Note: I added 'Elements are: ' at the begin, ',' between elements and '.' at
# the end.
"Elements are: element 1, element 2, element 3."
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails has `Array#to_sentence` that will do the same as `array.join(', ')` and additionally add "and " before the last item.

```
puts "Elements are: #{["element 1", "element 2", "element 3"].to_sentence}."
```

The rest, as you can see, is just putting it together.

Comment: @Backo this is probably what you want, but if you want exact same sentence as you created, replace `to_sentence` with `join(", ")`

Answer (score 1):

@coreyward's answer is close, but his suggestion's output doesn't match the requested output. This will give you exactly what you want:

```
puts "Elements are: #{array.to_sentence(last_word_connector: ', ')}."
```

See the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) for more examples and options.